# Single project with multiple submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a single project and I want to pull two more repositories from my server into it. I'm getting a problem where one of the submodules is pulling in code from both repositories, though.

One submodule needs to be within

```
/projectroot/application/models
```

The other

```
/projectroot/library/NameSpace
```

This is what I do:

```
cd projectroot
git submodule add ssh://user@xx.xx.xxx.xx:/var/repositories/models.git application/models
```

This works wonderfully; my application/models contains what it needs to. So I move onto the next:

```
git submodule add ssh://user@xx.xx.xxx.xx:/var/repositories/NameSpace.git library/NameSpace
```

I take a look in

```
/projectroot/library/NameSpace
```

and I have ALL files from both repositories in there. 
I should probably also note that

```
git submodule
```

correctly lists both submodules added as expected.

Am I missing something crucial here? Is it something I have done wrong with initializing the individual repositories? I have attempted this process ~3 times now.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the folder" in "I take a look in the folder...". Which folder?

Comment: @GregHewgill apologies, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this can be considered an answer, but I managed to fix it by re-cloning the entire project (before I had added the submodules). I then tried to add the submodules in again and it worked.

Somewhere along the line Git/ something else was getting confused.

Thanks anyway.